# RoR : Trying to map out complex model relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, backend

I'm trying to build a grocery list app which is unique to a user as there will be multiple users in the system. The user is able to create their own grocery list and in the products page section is where a user can select a product and save it into the list(s) made by the user (there will be a dropdown selection beside a "Add to list" button showing which list to save the selected product in). I have initially mapped out the relationship models however, I'm still unsure if I'd missed anything out and would like suggestions for improvements. This is what I did,

```
**user.rb**
has_many :grocery_lists
has_many :grocery_list_products through: :grocery_lists

**grocery_list.rb**
belongs_to :user
has_many :grocery_list_products
has_many :products through: :grocery_list_products

**product.rb**
has_many :grocery_lists
has_many :grocery_lists_products

**grocery_list_product.rb** #to connect grocery_list with product
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :grocery_list
belongs_to :user
```

Suggestions and tips are very much appreciated. Thank you.

Edited for further clarity.

Comment: I suggest posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com - another site in the stack exchange family.

Stackoverflow is for defined questions with specific answers.

Comment: @michaelward82, this question in its current form isn't ready for [codereview.se] - it needs to have actual implemented code to review.

Comment: @TobySpeight Noted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a number of different angles that could make this more complicated (ie: will there be a cart, or checkout down the road), but just going on what you have here:

you have misspelled `:grocery_list_products` as `:grocery_lists_products` under your product.rb

remove the reference to `:user` through the grocery_list_products table as well as the related :throughs, etc... it's redundant, you can get it through the grocery_list table.

If the product list is universal, what happens if the product is changed or deleted? will it automatically remove it from the list? if so then you will want to add a `dependent: :destroy` on your `has many :grocery_list_products`. Actually you should consider the `dependent: :destroy` logic on most of them, or handle them with a 'deactivated' column or something.

Comment: What if there are multiple users in the application? Then the association `has_many :grocery_list_products through: :grocery_lists` applies in the `user.rb` model right?